# Reactjs: What's best practice for working with class vs functional components?

Tags: reactjs

So both class-based and functional components can work with state and lifecycle methods, if I am not mistaken. And that it is possible to structure your app with both or just functional components using hooks.

I was wondering if there are actually best practices in the real world. What approach is usually used in a corporate environment? Is there a definite answer to this or do companies combine all approaches constantly?

Comment: if you want to work with the very confusing part of react named redux you can leave the hooks but in my opinion it's easier and more fun using hooks instead of redux

Answer (score 2):

Using class components is "mildly discouraged". Which means writing new code mostly using function components (unless there are compelling reasons not to) and not spending any time/resourses on rewriting existing codebase to move from class components to their functional counterparts.

An example of a compelling reason to use class component would be the need to optimise the component that uses Redux (e.g. is connected to Redux store) for performance to the extent beyond what hooks allow.

Comment: Can you share your sources for "mildly discouraged" please? In some places I'm reading classes are better, and in other places that FCs are better, but I could not find an official statement yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here we are changing all class components to functional components using hooks. Depending on component complexity we don't change for now.
But this is not a rule, actually, this is not recommended.
[here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html) is a React blog that covers this.